# Could not parse the remainder: '${profiles['user']}' from '${profiles['user']}

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

```js
    const data = '{{ search_user }}'
    const rdata = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'))
    const input = document.getElementById('user-input_products')

    let filteredArr = []

    input.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
        box.innerHTML = ""
        filterMax = (fn, c) => x => c && fn(x) && c--
        filter = profiles=> profiles['full_name'].includes(e.target.value)
        max = 30
        filteredArr = rdata.filter(filterMax(filter, max))
        if (filteredArr.length > 0) {
            filteredArr.map(profiles=>{
                box.innerHTML += `<li><a href="{% url 'user_num' ${profiles['user']} %}">${profiles['full_name']}</a></li>`
            })
        } else {
            box.innerHTML = "No result found"
        }
    })
```

And when i want to pass id to django url inside of **innerHTML** it's give me this error:

`Could not parse the remainder: '${profiles["user"]}' from '${profiles["user"]}'`

How can i fix that?

```
rdata:
[
  {
    "user": 28,
    "full_name": "John"
  },
  {
    "user": 35,
    "full_name": "Robert"
  },
  {
    "user": 37,
    "full_name": "Mary"
  },
  {
    "user": 38,
    "full_name": "Jennifer"
  },
]
```

Comment: May you share `data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"')`? Is `rdata` what you expect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix server side Python code with frontend javascript code like this. Django Templates sees `${profiles['user']}` as a simple string. To fix this you can store a path prefix in a JS variable and combine the user links with JS template literal:

```
const path_prefix = "{% url 'user_num' %}"
const data = '{{ search_user }}'
const rdata = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'))
const input = document.getElementById('user-input_products')

let filteredArr = []

input.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
    box.innerHTML = ""
    filterMax = (fn, c) => x => c && fn(x) && c--
    filter = profiles=> profiles['full_name'].includes(e.target.value)
    max = 30
    filteredArr = rdata.filter(filterMax(filter, max))
    if (filteredArr.length > 0) {
        filteredArr.map(profiles=>{
            box.innerHTML += `<li><a href="${path_prefix}${profiles['user']}">${profiles['full_name']}</a></li>`
        })
    } else {
        box.innerHTML = "No result found"
    }
})
```

If the path for the `user_num` view function is `user_num/`, then `${path_prefix}${profiles['user']}` will produce e.g. `user_num/28`. You may have to create a new URL definition if `user_num` function requires an argument, or you can just put in the actual path directly, e.g.: `user_num/${profiles['user']}`.